# VBA - Find a column with a specific header and find sum of all the rows in that column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large sheet. I have to set multiple filters in that sheet to columns headers in dynamic positions. Once the filters are set, I have to find the particular column in the sheet having the column header "Nov" and then obtain the sum of values in that column and import that particular sum value into a different worksheet.
I've written the code up until the part where i can set the filters to multiple columns, but I'm finding it difficult to find the column header and add that column. Below is the code I've written so far.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim colName As Long
Dim colName1 As Long
Dim colName2 As Long
Dim r As Long

SearchV = Range("A8:DD8").Find(What:="Nov", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, SearchV).End(xlUp).Row

colName = Range("A8:DD8").Find(What:="Teams", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

colName1 = Range("A8:DD8").Find(What:="Items", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

colName2 = Range("A8:DD8").Find(What:="Domain", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$DD$9999").AutoFilter Field:=colName, Criteria1:="ST Test",     Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$DD$9999").AutoFilter Field:=colName1, Criteria1:="Variance", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="(Blanks)"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$DD$9999").AutoFilter Field:=colName2, Criteria1:="9S", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="(Blanks)"
```

The column headers always start from the 8th row. Some uesless information is present in the rows above. So what I want is, suppose the column 'Nov' is in H row. The sum should be calculated from H9 to the end of the last row. I had used this formula when the column was in 'H' column.

```
Cells(lastrow + 1, colName3).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,H9:H" & lastrow & ")"
```

But the column 'Nov' won't always be present in row 'H', so i'm not able to figure out how to change my code to pick the column dynamically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ensure that you fully qualify your objects and also put in a check whether `.Find` returns something or not. Here is an example.

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

Now try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A8:DD8").Find(What:="Nov", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If Found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            col = aCell.Column
            colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

            lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> This is your range
            Set Rng = .Range(colName & "8:" & colName & lRow)

            Debug.Print Rng.Address
        '~~> If not found
        Else
            MsgBox "Nov Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Siddharth. I managed to pull off most of my work with that. But the actual problem is managing to add the sum of rows. I'm using this code right now.


`SumV = SV & "9:"`

`SumW = SV & lRow`

`Cells(lRow + 1, SV).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,SumV:SumW)"`

But this is returning the following value in Excel "=SUBTOTAL(9,SumV:SumW)"

And I'm getting #NAME? error.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. Whatever you had mentioned as colName in your code, I renamed it to SV, since I was already using the colName variable elsewhere. So basically, what I'm trying to do is concatenate the column and the row to obtain a certain value (Eg. W9).
So I got the value of W9 for SumV and W2128 for SumW. But when I use the Subtotal function, the same gets inserted instead of the actual value. I tried using them like this as well. `=SUBTOTAL(9," & SumV & ":" & SumW & ")`. But even that is throwing an exception.

Comment: You have to use it like `rng.Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9," & SumV & ":" & SumW & ")"`

Comment: I am using it that way. `Cells(lRow + 1, SV).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9," & SumV & ":" & SumW & ")"` . 

I am getting Application-Defined or Object-Defined error. I've defined lRow  & SV as long. SumV and SumW as string. Does that matter?

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of what gets inserted? You may upload the pic on www.wikisend.com?

Comment: `SV as Long`? Why? As per your earlier comment `Whatever you had mentioned as colName in your code, I renamed it to SV` So `SV` should have been declared as a `String`

Comment: or better can you upload your file on www.wikisend.com and let me have a look at the file.

Comment: I've uploaded the document here.. [http://wikisend.com/download/723486/11.xlsm] .. Please refer to Sheet 5.. The code I've written is in Module 2. Please let me know once I fetch the sum value, how do I export it into a different Excel Sheet.

Comment: You have an extra ":". Either change `SumV = SV & "9:"` to `SumV = SV & "9"` or `"=SUBTOTAL(9," & SumV & ":" & SumW & ")"` to `"=SUBTOTAL(9," & SumV & SumW & ")"`

Comment: That was pretty silly. Thanks a lot for your help and time. Its working perfectly now.