# Excel VBA Select column number issue in code Quick Fix?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that splits my data up onto multiple sheets by changing Slot values (SlotA,SlotB,SlotC). The location of the Slot column can change with different incoming data therefore I need it to find the location of the column each time. vcol is the location of the column and works when it equals a number (Ex:vcol=2) however when I try and have it find the column it does not work. I have also tried having it read a cell with `vcol = StickNumberMacro.Cells(10, 2).Value` where the cell uses =MATCH("Chamber Name",ImportSheetRaw!1:1,1) to find the location and they did not work either.

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Slot",ImportSheetRaw.Range("1:1"),0)  'PROBLEM
Set ws = Sheets("ImportSheetRaw")
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:C1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: You should really indent your code for readability.

Comment: See how to find a column by its header [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122393/vba-find-a-column-with-a-specific-header-and-find-sum-of-all-the-rows-in-that)

Comment: I think the issue has to do with it not reading the column location as an integer